# ONVIF compatible open source streaming server for Linux based systems

Tags: streaming, ip-camera, onvif

I am currently working on an ip-camera project. Initially we decided to use [live 555](http://www.live555.com/) as a streaming server, but later on we had a requirement to make the camera [ONVIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Video_Interface_Forum) compliant.

I'm not sure about this, but **live 555** is not an ONVIF compliant yet. The only relevant link i could find regarding onvif is [this](http://lists.live555.com/pipermail/live-devel/2010-July/012400.html). Our camera is running embedded Linux, so we are looking for ONVIF compliant open source streaming server.

If someone can tell:

1. Is **live 555** ONVIF compliant now?
2. Is there any other open source, ONVIF compatible streaming server for Linux based systems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Live 555 has no ONVIF specific features however it does share the RTSP/RTP standard with ONVIF. So you could certainly create an ONVIF server that incorporates live 555 to handle the streaming at RTSP level but you would have to implement the ONVIF specific parts yourself.

2) Never come across any such open source server.